# TFS Team Build 2010 - queue build as a named user

Tags: tfs, build

After much messing around I've got CI implemented onto our test server. A custom workflow template builds and deploys 2 web apps (different servers), a database and a windows service. This is brill and takes all the worry out of deploying a test app.

I want to move this over to staging and live (queued manually), but doing it like this the TFS service account would need permissions on IIS for the web apps, DBOwner on the database and local admin on the service box. This is a big no-no for our tech guys!

What we could do is just give these permissions before we run the build and remove afterwards, but this means maintaining a list of what permissions to change where - ruining the convenience of one-click deployment a bit.

Ideally we'd just get the build to run using the account of the tech services guy whos got admin network-wide, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that via the TFS Administrator Console.

If you haven't configured your build machine, then you can choose the user during the configuration phase. You should see a Configuration Wizard page that allows you to choose a user account like this:

[image]

If your build machine is already configured, go to your build machine, then run %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools\TfsMgmt.exe, then go to "Build Configuration", click at "Properties" link of the Build Service to open the Properties dialog, then click "stop to make changes" on the dialog, and you can change the account from the built-in account to a user one:

[image]

Comment: I assume he wants to automate switching the accounts.  In that case you might be better off with a seperate agent that runs as the elevated account.  Mark that agent with a "Production" tag and force the production build definition to target that tag.

Comment: Unfortunately our tech guys won't go for that. They want the password for the account to be specified at the time of running the build, so we don't have a network account sat around with lots of power over our apps. I've given up now and moved onto WiX installers.